# javascript async/await unhandledRejection not triggered

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, es6-promise, hapi.js

I am developing a RESTful API using HapiJS.

I'm using HapiJS v17 to take advantage of async/await.

My Intentions is to not handle exceptions in each route but to have a centralized place to handle all **unhandledRejection**.

The way I'm trying to achieve this is by listening to the `unhandledRejection` event early when the server starts.

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
    console.log('Unhandled Rejection at:', p, 'reason:', reason);
});
```

And then for example, in my business logic code, I intentionally do not catch rejected promises(for example a database error) hoping that I will be able to process it in the callback of `process.on('unhandledRejection'`

But the `console.log` statement is never triggered.

For example:

```
handler: async (request, h) => {
            const user = request.user;

            const userIdToUpdate = request.params.id;

            const firstName = request.payload.firstName;
            const lastName = request.payload.lastName;
            const roles = request.payload.roles;

            const updatedUser = await UserCtrl.updateUser(userIdToUpdate, firstName, lastName, roles, user.tenantId.toString());

            const response = h.response(updatedUser.sanitize());
            response.type('application/json');
            return response;
        }
```

`UserCtrl.updateUser` returns a Promise, let's say the database connection is down, I'm assuming that the Promise should be rejected but why is the `process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {` is not being triggered?

Comment: why you want to handle all error at one place, what if you want to perform any other operation after getting the error.

Comment: Error raised by "UserCtrl.updateUser" will go "up" to Promise returned by "handler". Do you skip catching of error for this function also?

Comment: then I would add a try catch whenever I want to do something custom

Comment: how are you using handler?

Comment: handler is called by HapiJS

Comment: Seems HapiJS has 'catch' for result of 'handler' call - therefore no 'unhandledRejection'  event triggered

Comment: not according to this https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/3658

Comment: Release notes are too broad. Looking at the code - seems error catched there: https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/lib/request.js#L157

Answer (score 1):

I think HapiJS catches error of your request handler.

Looking at the code - seems error [catched there](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/lib/request.js#L157).

Not sure in what format and under what conditions it is rethrown further.

I would not rely on framework for such logic anyway and at least wrap all handlers with own wrapper and log all errors there.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing a **PreResponse** hook that will check if the response is an Error and act accordingly

```
server.ext('onPreResponse', (request, h) => {
            const response = request.response;
            if (!response.isBoom) {
                return h.continue;
            }

            let error = response;
            if (!error.message && error.output && error.output.payload) {
                return error.output.payload;
            }

            error = new Error(error.message);
            return Boom.boomify(error, {statusCode: 400});
        });
```